# Getting Email Address of the receiver dynamically in the Email body

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

The Main Agenda behind this question is that I want to replace a dynamic holder in my Email body  with the email address who has received the mail

We would be using the standard procedure using asp.net, i.e. Making an Email Body then by using the smtp.send(), would be sending the mail to the concerned email address. But I would like to have a place holder in my email body (e.g. Thanks for reading the mail, xxx@yyy.com), such that the xxx@yyy.com gets replaced by the one who is openeing the mail.

Now here comes the interesting part..... the user that i sent the mail (e.g xxx@yyy.com) if forwards the mail to some other email address (e.g abc@zzz.com), then when abc@zzz.com opens the mail he would see "Thanks for reading the mail, abc@zzz.com".

Is it possible in the first place ?

Comment: with some "malicous techniques" this is possible BUT really a big problem to implement robustly (you would rely on partially undocumented behaviour of specific eMail clients and/or some client-side vulnerability and/or some bad client-side setting)... WHY would you ever want to do such a thing ???

Comment: Just for the sake of good user experience, may be !

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe what you're asking is possible. When you generate and send the email, the email body is composed on the server side, hence you have full control over it. Once the user has it in their email box, you no longer can change the content of that email.

An Email's content can't change - that kind of behavior would be similar to you running your code on the client's machine without their permission, i.e. a virus and is generally frowned upon.